# add Closure method to metaClass of groovy class

Tags: groovy, closures, metaclass

i knewt how to add method to metaClass of `java.util.List` :

```
java.util.List.metaClass.average={

       return delegate.sum()/delegate.size();
}
```

and if i have `def myList=[new Person(score:1),new Person(score:2)]` , i call to new method as following:

```
 myList.average();
```

However, i want to call it as following :

```
   myList.average{it.score}
```

How can i add this method to metaClass to be called as Closure( `{}` and not `()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
List.metaClass.average = { Closure c ->
    delegate.sum( c ) / delegate.size()
}
```

Comment: Man.metaClass.thanks={println "thank 1000 times"}; def tim_yates=new Man(); tim_yates.thanks();

Comment: @AbdennourToumi `[76,79,76].collect{(char)it}.join()` ;-)